# Is it possible to alias an internal command?

Tags: eshell, term, commands

Since I discovered `multi-term`, I use it exclusively over `term` or `eshell`. But, I'm lazy and would prefer to be able to simply type *term* to activate `multi-term`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, with [defalias](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Functions.html#index-function-aliases-752).

Put this code in your init file:

```
(defalias 'term 'multi-term)
```

This will make it so calling `M-x term` calls the same function as `M-x multi-term`.